# How do I pipe something from the command line to a new Github gist?

Tags: shell, github, gist

I don't know if this exists yet, but I'd love to be able to do:

```
$ cat mygist.js | gh new gist
```

And have it return the URL (and possibly copy it to the clipboard / open it in the browser).

Comment: That's a cool idea =) if it doesn't exist yet I think I can write a script to do that when I have time

Comment: There is no really easy way to achieve this common task.

Comment: This exists now as `cat cool.txt | gh gist create`. https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_gist_create

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this gem: https://github.com/defunkt/gist

Worked for me ^_^

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: _Do_ run `gist --login` before attempting to upload any gists. Not doing so will upload your gist as an anonymous user.

Answer (score 29):

Seems like GitHub has a simple REST API, including methods for [creating Gists](http://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#create-a-gist). Just for fun:

```
$ curl -X POST \
    --data-binary '{"files": {"file1.txt": {"content": "Hello, SO"}}}' \
    https://api.github.com/gists
```

This successfully created [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/6f4892ca28b69df58bb1). I guess it's enough to get you started.

Comment: is there a way to use a filename instead of `"Hello, SO"` so that i can stream the file to gist?

Comment: @kirill_igum: you can put `$(cat /home/user/filename)` instead of `Hello, SO` (but leave the double quotes around it). You would also have to replace the single quotes around the entire JSON string with double quotes and escape all the double quotes.

Comment: Using `curl -u user:pass ...` will also ensure the gist gets owned by "you".

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple bash script that takes a filename and makes it a gist.

```
function msg() {
  echo -n '{"description":"","public":"false","files":{"file1.txt":{"content":"'
  awk '{gsub(/"/,"\\\""); printf "%s\\n",$0}' "$1"
  echo '"}}'
}

[ "$#" -ne 1 ] && echo "Syntax: gist.sh filename" && exit 1
[ ! -r "$1" ] && echo "Error: unable to read $1" && exit 2

msg "$1" | curl -v -d '@-' https://api.github.com/gists
```

FYI: gist replies with the post body, so if the file is big, perhaps grep just the relevant parts of the reply.

Comment: I get a 400 error "Problems parsing JSON" doing this.

Comment: apparently I'd only done oneliner gists with that, newlines also need to be escaped, updated post.

Answer (score 1):

As Ronie said above, there is a gist gem which provides a gist command that you can use from your terminal to upload content to https://gist.github.com/

To upload the contents of a.rb just:

```
gist a.rb
```

More info  http://defunkt.io/gist/

Answer (score 0):

Have the same desire I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/gistup and fork the repository to https://github.com/CrandellWS/mkg because the developer did not want to support Windows which was the operating system being used at the time. So I reworked the npm package to work on windows as well as linux and apple...

Full source is available on GitHub:
https://github.com/CrandellWS/mkg

Installation is simple with npm

```
npm install -g mkg
```

Use is discribed on the npmjs package page:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gistup

Once installed simply `cd` to which every directory you want to make a gist from...(remeber there are no subfolders with Gists)

and run the command:

```
mkg
```

and it will open your new gist in a broswer...additionally you will be able to control it like a normal git from there... just no subfolders...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41233970/1815624

Answer (score 0):

A super simple command I like to use for making gists out of `diff`s is:

`git diff origin master -U15 | gist -t diff`

Where `15` is the line spacing you can have before and after the change (So it's easier to see differences in larger files.)

`-t` is the `type` flag.