# How to create a gist on command line

Tags: github, github-api, gist

I am trying to create a gist from bash, and I have tried many versions scripts I could get, but none are working.

This seems like a correct one, but it does not work also.

```
curl -X POST -d '{"public":true,"files":{"test.txt":{"content":"String file contents"}}}' https://api.github.com/gists
```

I have a `test.txt` file with content I would like to create the gist, but it won't work.  It says, `invalid email`, if I try to add `-u USER` or `-u USER:PASS` it still won't work saying `"message": "Problems parsing JSON",` ..

I don't know what is wrong. the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#create-a-gist) does not provide much except for this line:

> `POST /gists` 
>   as you can see, I am passing the test.txt file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've just tried

```
curl -X POST -d '{"public":true,"files":{"test.txt":{"content":"String file contents"}}}' -u mgarciaisaia:mypassword https://api.github.com/gists
```

and it worked: https://gist.github.com/mgarciaisaia/fa51238073eb2cf508aa

I don't see any problem in your command.

Comment: btw: I have been trying to replace the `test.txt` and the `String file.. ` with variables, but being inside single quotes, it does not work. Do you have any idea how to pass a variable inside single quotes?

Comment: But, how can we gist file.cpp snippet using that?

Comment: Now it says "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64025613/9130688 response is valid for 2020

Comment: How can I post from a `.log` file ?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa you'd need to read the file's content into a variable, and include that in the payload. That would imply changing the quotes and escaping, too. Maybe there's a new endpoint now?

Answer (score 33):

Recently GitHub CLI released.
So you can now use it instead.

Just install it to your system (https://github.com/cli/cli#installation)

The authenticate (it's pretty simple)

```
gh auth login
```

After you logged in you can simply create a new gist by:

```
gh gist create -d "my test gist" -f some_local_file.txt  test_gist
```

For more details you can use help:

```
gh <command> <subcommand> --help
```

Comment: To use it on [NixOS](https://nixos.org/) or with the [Nix](https://nixos.org/) package manager, use `nix-shell -p github-cli`.

Comment: @Nickolay Kondratenko I am trying to push new local file into gist but its giving me an error 
`failed to collect files for posting: failed to read file test_gist: open test_gist: no such file or directory`
`gh gist create -d "Snwflake-Queries" -f Snflk_Query.sql test_gist`

Comment: @Karthik that's because test_gist file doesn't exist. Your command should be the following `gh gist create -d "Snwflake-Queries" Snflk_Query.sql`

Comment: @Karthik from help: `-f, --filename string   Provide a filename to be used when reading from STDIN`

Comment: @NickolayKondratenko Thanks a lot . Whats the command to overwrite the same file with new changes

Answer (score 15):

This question is old, so I am not sure it is still relevant.

On Ubuntu (at least on 18.04), you can try the `gist` package, which will install the `gist-paste` command that you can use (given you have a git account already) as below:

1) Get a gist OAuth2 token (it will create a ~/.gist file with the token). You have to do it once only:

```
$ gist-paste --login
```

Then, you can send your files, for instance:

```
$ gist-paste your-file.txt
$ cat .emacs.d/init.el | gist-paste -t el
```

There are many options: You can send file type/description (as above second example), delete gists, open gist in browser, etc... See `gist-paste(1)` or try `gist-paste --help`.

If you already have a gist token, you don't need to run `gist-paste --login`, just copy your `~/.gitconfig`'s `oauth-token` to `~/.gist`.
For example, if you have in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[github]
    oauth-token = foobar123
```

Just create a `~/.gist` file with one line containing "foobar123".

[Edit] If your distribution does not provide the package, the project page is:
https://github.com/defunkt/gist

Comment: Confirmed to work on Ubuntu 16.04 but I just did gist finename.txt

Answer (score 4):

I've just started using [http://defunkt.io/gist](http://defunkt.io/gist/), it makes things pretty simple:

```sh
# upload string to file
gist -f test.txt <<< "hello string"

# upload a file
gist test.txt
```

Comment: This is amazing! To install it use `sudo gem install gist` and then `gist --login` and put the 8 digit code into `github.com`. To write multiple lines just type `gist` and exit after several lines with `CTRL-D`.

Comment: Or, if one is on [NixOS](https://nixos.org/) or using [Nix](https://nixos.org/) as a package manager, use `nix-shell -p gist`.

Answer (score 3):

Have the same desire I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/gistup and fork the repository to https://github.com/CrandellWS/mkg because the developer did not want to support Windows which was the operating system being used at the time. So I reworked the npm package to work on windows as well as linux and apple...

Full source is available on GitHub:
https://github.com/CrandellWS/mkg

Installation is simple with npm

```
npm install -g mkg
```

Use is discribed on the npmjs package page:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gistup

Once installed simply `cd` to which every directory you want to make a gist from...(remeber there are no subfolders with Gists)

and run the command:

```
mkg
```

and it will open your new gist in a broswer...additionally you will be able to control it like a normal git from there... just no subfolders...

Answer (score 3):

As of [September 2020](https://github.blog/2020-09-17-github-cli-1-0-is-now-available/), creating gists is one of the features of [GitHub's official command line tool `gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli).

E.g., on MacOS:

```sh
brew install gh
gh auth login  # Follow steps.
gh gist create myfile.txt  # Creates a private gist.
```

More options are available. `gh gist create --help` gives:

```
Create a new GitHub gist with given contents.

Gists can be created from one or multiple files. Alternatively, pass "-" as
file name to read from standard input.

By default, gists are private; use '--public' to make publicly listed ones.


USAGE
  gh gist create [<filename>... | -] [flags]

FLAGS
  -d, --desc string       A description for this gist
  -f, --filename string   Provide a filename to be used when reading from STDIN
  -p, --public            List the gist publicly (default: private)

INHERITED FLAGS
  --help   Show help for command

EXAMPLES
  # publish file 'hello.py' as a public gist
  $ gh gist create --public hello.py

  # create a gist with a description
  $ gh gist create hello.py -d "my Hello-World program in Python"

  # create a gist containing several files
  $ gh gist create hello.py world.py cool.txt

  # read from standard input to create a gist
  $ gh gist create -

  # create a gist from output piped from another command
  $ cat cool.txt | gh gist create

LEARN MORE
  Use 'gh <command> <subcommand> --help' for more information about a command.
  Read the manual at https://cli.github.com/manual
```

Comment: If i want to udpate the existing file in the gist , whats the command using gh

Comment: Use `gh gist edit {<gist ID> | <gist URL>} -f <filename>`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your system info so I'm using mine.

Install:

install: `winget install --id GitHub.cli`

Note: you must launch a new cli or close and restart your cli after installing so that your cli knows that the path is changed.

upgrade: `winget upgrade --id GitHub.cli`

public: `gh gist create --public hello.py`

private:`gh gist create hello.py`

You'll get a url, like this:
[image: Simple and effective, the url is like 4dad2955bffb6443792b385a972063c]