# Extract content from a GitHub .md file and put into a gist via GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api, github-pages

I want to be able to extract specific parts of a GitHub .md file and create a gist via the GitHub API. Possible?

Comment: Yes. (Ask a vague question, get a useless answer.) What GitHub `.md` file? Do you mean a `.md` file that is committed in some GitHub repository? What would you want to extract? With which language? What have you tried?...

Comment: Let's say I want to extract 5 lines of text from a ReadMe.md file in my personal repo. I'd like to use the command line and pull those lines from Github using the Github API. 

Then I'd like to "pipe" the extracted text into a Github gist file.

Possible? Haven't tried anything yet, as I can't find the API commands in Github to perform the operations.

Comment: Use `curl` and [RawGit](http://rawgit.com) to access the raw file, then Unix tools to cut them up. Use [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552335/how-do-i-pipe-something-from-the-command-line-to-a-new-github-gist) to post a gist.

Comment: Thank you @Amadan . This will be very helpful.